# In flutter, data response from REST API sometime get null With GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I use `getConnect` API from **getX**, and check validate the response got from the API. But at some unexpected time (**not happen always, mostly occur with android version 10 device**), only got null from the API response. Actually I suppose requesting API may get **FAIL** or **SUCCESS** for every request. Now only got null response. Why this happen, **is it issue of the package** or **android device version error** or, how can I fix it?

```dart
class ApiServices with DataStorageMixin {

  final Logger log = Logger();
  static GetConnect? _instance;

  ApiServices._() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = GetConnect(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10));
      _instance!.httpClient.addRequestModifier<dynamic>((request) {
        log.i("Request method: ${request.method}\nUrl: ${request.url}");
        log.i("Request header: ${request.headers}");
        return request;
      });
      _instance!.httpClient.addResponseModifier((request, response) {
        log.i("Response is : ${response.status.code}\nBody: ${response.body}");
        return response;
      });
    }
  }

  factory ApiServices.instance() => ApiServices._();

 

  void validateResponse({
    required Response? response,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onSuccess,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onRequestError,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onServerError,
  }) {
    print('RB --- ${response!.body}');
    if (response!.body != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = response.body;
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        bool isSuccessResponse = responseBody['err'] == CODE_SUCCESS ||
            responseBody['err'] == CODE_NEW_USER ||
            responseBody['err'] == CODE_REGISTERED_USER ||
            responseBody['err'] == CODE_CREATE;
        if (isSuccessResponse) {
          onSuccess(responseBody);
        } else {
          onRequestError(responseBody);
        }
      } else {
        onServerError(responseBody);
      }
    }
  }

  

  Future<void> apiPostCall({
    String? bearerToken,
    required String endPoint,
    bool isFullEndPoint = false,
    Map<String, dynamic>? data,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onSuccess,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onRequestError,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onServerError,
  }) async {
    // try {
    Response? response = await _instance!.post(
      isFullEndPoint ? endPoint : '$BASE_URL$endPoint',
      data,
      headers: await getHeader(
        url: endPoint,
        bearerToken: bearerToken,
      ),
    );
    validateResponse(
      response: response,
      onSuccess: onSuccess,
      onRequestError: onRequestError,
      onServerError: onServerError,
    );
    // } catch (e) {
    //   onServerError({'error': e});
    // }
  }
}
```

---

In this method `validateResponse()`, I log `response.body` and it got `null` but for unexpected time (Not happen every request).

```dart
  void validateResponse({
    required Response? response,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onSuccess,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onRequestError,
    required Callback<Map<String, dynamic>> onServerError,
  }) {
    print('RB --- ${response!.body}');
    if (response!.body != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = response.body;
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        bool isSuccessResponse = responseBody['err'] == CODE_SUCCESS ||
            responseBody['err'] == CODE_NEW_USER ||
            responseBody['err'] == CODE_REGISTERED_USER ||
            responseBody['err'] == CODE_CREATE;
        if (isSuccessResponse) {
          onSuccess(responseBody);
        } else {
          onRequestError(responseBody);
        }
      } else {
        onServerError(responseBody);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the screen shoot of response.
[image]